# How do I enter input in Visual Studio Code while debugging and also enter integer arguments for my program?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While trying to debug some of my (very noob) programs for C++ in Visual Studio Code, I don't seem to be able to enter any input in the debug console and also don't know how to apply integer arguments to my program.

Problem with entering input:
The problem is that since my program requires input of a character, the debug console just hangs there after inputting a "y".

[image: Problem entering input in debug console]

Problem with adding arguments:
The problem is that VS Code requires a String for arguments, so if I enter "2 4" as arguments, only the 2 is recognized by my program as the first argument.

[image: Problem with adding arguments in VS Code]

Thanks in advance for any help you are willing to offer! (In the meantime I'll be using VS 2017, which, after plenty of startup-problems, I have finally managed to get running.)

Comment: Add `args` in `launch.json` file. Read [this docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) for more information.

Comment: I did that and that's why I said it requires a String: in the launch.json-file all entries are stored in String-format.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This question is 100% programming and should be asked at StackOverflow instead. They will be able to better help you.

Answer (score 1):

As OP provided Visual Studio in his question, the following procedure is written using MSVC. But one can use GCC/mingw-w64 toolchain using same procedure but with some little change. Please do not confuse with Visual Studio (VS) and Visual Studio Code (VSCode).

### Requirements:

- Visual Studio Code.
- [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) for VSCode.
- Microsoft C++ (MSVC) compiler toolset.

### Sample C Program:

This program takes two char arguments (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]`). Converts it to integer, then adds them.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s First Second\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int first = atoi(argv[1]);
    int second = atoi(argv[2]);
    int result = first + second;
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

### Procedure:

- Open Command Prompt (CMD). Run Developer command prompt for Visual Studio with this command. The command may vary with Visual Studio versions and editions.

```bat
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

- In that very CMD window, `cd` into the project folder and open VSCode (`code`) in that folder (`.`) with this following command:

```bat
cd MyProject
code.exe .
```

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette. Click `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)`. This will add `c_cpp_properties.json` file in `.vscode` folder. Create a build task for MSVC (`tasks.json`) and debug settings (`launch.json`). This will add default setting files.
- Add `cl.exe` as the compile name and change source file name.
- Add the arguments in `launch.json` file. The arguments are character type but the program converts those to integers. For example, `"args": ["10", "20"]`.
- Compile the project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Add the breakpoint.

### Further readings

- [Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)
- [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you! I managed to get my program running with correct output in MSVS, but not VC, since it doesn't seem to accept my arguments in string format with a comma in between, or a space, I always get an outrageous value for the exponent.

Comment: @Afrim124 Your sample program is incorrect. The main only accepts arguments as array of char pointers. In VScode, the arguments are passed in that `args` JSON array.

Comment: Thank you for persisting, 'cause I found the problem. It is because I didn't start VC with the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt. Then the exponent and the output are fine. I still can't enter input in the debug console, though.